# How copy information from Sheets to PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, excel

i am new developer in PHP and need learn if there is a way to copy content from an excel sheet and paste it into a php site, simulating an excel spreadsheet in PHP and be able to edit the pasted information.

Finally enter this information in a SQL database.

I know that you can upload a file and recover the data from there, but it is not an option in this project

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theres a lot of aspects to what you want to achieve but a few points to get you started. You can use the [JExcel](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel) plugin in order to simulate a spreadsheet in the browser, however the spreadsheet itself uses HTML and JavaScript. Its possible to copy cells from excel and paste them into the JExcel table, you can then edit cells, add new cells etc.

You can then pass the data from the table to PHP using an AJAX call (JExcel provides methods to do this), im currently doing a project that does exactly this and it works very well. You can then do what you want with the saved data, e.g. insert it into a DB from PHP.

Hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score -1):

[PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) is what you are looking for. There is another library which is dead, phpexcel, spreadsheet is a decendent of this.